# How to determine relationship or correlation among categorical input variables or between input and output var in classification?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I starts to learn machine learning by myself.

I have a set of input variables (categorical and continuous): job (retired, manager, technician, etc.) education (high school, unknown, bachelor, master, etc.) , duration of contact, age, marital; etc.... output variable (yes or no) (agree to purchase new product?)

First of all I want to analyze the dataset, but I do not know how to find correlation between input and output variable for discrete input data in python?

Should I clear all the missing data (unknown)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things come to mind:
1. Look at how features a correlated
2. Look at how purchased vs. not-purchased statistical distributions look like

**Feature correlation**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'job': ['retired', 'retired', 'manager', 'manager', 'manager', 'technician', 'technician', None, None],
        'education': ['high', 'high', 'master', 'unknown', 'master', 'master', 'high', 'unknown', 'master'],
        'duration_of_contact': [3, 1, 5, 3, 1, 9 ,8, 3, 1],
        'age': [50, 65, 30, 29, 38, 42, 25, 10, 10],
        'married': [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        'purchase': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
    })

sns.heatmap(df.corr())
```

[image]

**Statistical properties**

You could look at the distributions of the two cases when purchase is True, and when purchase is False:

```
sns.boxplot(x="purchase", y="age", data=df)
```

[image]

See more plots you can use from seaborn: https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html